# Can TOR prevent my ISP from seeing what I download?

Tags: monitoring, tor

Having issues with my ISP monitoring my activity and blocking my internet access when they see something they don't like. Can I utilize TOR to prevent this monitoring with out tipping off my ISP to my security?

Comment: You are better to use a VPN service.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Using TOR will prevent your ISP from seeing exactly what you are doing.

Your ISP will, however, be able to see that you are using TOR based on the "exit nodes" seen in the packet - they could block you based on those.

They will also be able to see your packet sizes and frequency of packets, and mmight be able to make some inferences as to the kind of thing you are doing - although not exactly what you are doing !

Answer (score 0):

Tor can do this, but it's slow and not without issues. Some sites may block your IP if you visit them using Tor. So while downloading what you need and at the same time browsing the internet, you may find yourself locked out certain sites. This is the result of blacklisting, which should not happen if you use Tor just for browsing, but it has happened to me at least once.

A better solution is probably to use a (paid) VPN provider. This will be less suspicious to your ISP, speed is better, and your anonimity is probably better protected, depending on their terms.

You need a paid VPN provider, and you can find several that offer a free trial period of several days. Prices start at about $5 per month.

Comment: Anonymity is not better protected though a VPN provider - for a start you need to register with them - no requirement to do so with Tor.  Similarly all traffic flows through a single point, so a compromise of the output, combined with traffic analysis gets the adversary everything, unlike Tor.  I agree it will be less suspicious to the ISP and you will likely experience better speed through a VPN.